# Existence of a Triangle with a Multiplicity

Tags: geometry

A finite set $S$ of unit squares is chosen out of a large grid of unit squares. The
squares of $S$ are tiled with isosceles right triangles of hypotenuse $2$ so that the triangles do not overlap each other, do not extend past $S$, and all of $S$ is fully covered by the triangles. Additionally, the hypotenuse of each triangle lies along a grid line, and the vertices of the triangles lie at the corners of the squares. Show that the number of triangles must be a multiple of $4$.

*Suggested Answer:*
He draw a directed graph. For each unit square we use a vertex. Now start at any vertex and create a Hamiltonian directed cycle, where A->B if one half-square of A and one half-square of B create a hypotenuse-2 triangle.

We obtain a polygon that is the Hamiltonian directed cycle. If a side of the polygon is between two turns in opposite directions, it has even length, otherwise it has odd length.

Now for each 270º corner, substitute it by three 90º corners, this will add 4 units to the total perimeter so the total perimeter modulo 4 hasn't changed. Now we have a (maybe self-intersecting and non-convex) polygon where all the corners are 90º. All the sides measure an odd integer. Now it is trivial that the perimeter is a multiple of 4, because the polygon is equivalent to a rectangle with all sides odd.

Comment: This was a problem asked during an open mathematical competition for the purposes of gaining an unnatural and unfair advantage. It had been locked and hidden. Although it is now unlocked, since the competition has passed, this is abusive and bad; and I downvoted. It is unfortunate, as the question is pleasant and the answer good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Constructing such a cover forces $S$ to be made of $2\times 2$ squares. How many triangles with hypothenuse $2$ axis-aligned with the squares do you need to cover each of these $2\times 2$ squares?

Comment: AlexR: this is USAMTS Round 3 problem set (problem 5)